# JavaScript - How to add links to the DOM

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, so this question will probably be easy for you guys:

I'm trying to add an additional URL link to the DOM, but my current code isn't working. In my mind, my code should work perfectly, but the code itself must think otherwise.

```
// Additional URL link that will go under the first one
// Establish a connection in the DOM
var target = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

// We need to create new element
var newLink = document.createElement("a");

// We have the new "a" tag created, but we also have to add some things to it
newLink.setAttribute("href", "http://www.ign.com/");

// Now we need to add some text for the end user to click for the new "a" element
newLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click Me!"));

// Finally, add the new element and we're golden
target.appendChild(newLink);
```

Comment: Why do you need nested links?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? (Anyway, `getElementsByTagName` returns a *collection*, not a single element - so at least the last line won't work.)

Comment: Also `target` is a NodeList. What does the console say?

Comment: It's for a homework assignment. I e-mailed my professor and she gave me some pointers; however, the code is still not working, and the assignment is due tonight :(
When I say "not working," the actually URL link and clickable text is not appearing.
The console says "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'appendChild'"

Comment: I'm sure this must be obvious, but there's already a link that I am referencing, to gain an entry point into the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `target.appendChild(newLink);` to `target[0].appendChild(newLink);`

"target" in your code is <strike>an array</strike> a [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) of all the <strike>links</strike> *A* elements, so to pick the first one you need to say target[0]

Comment: *target* is a (live) [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), not an array. See the [*getElementsByTagName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) method of the document interface.